# How to use Partition Discovery in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given the next structure in HDFS with parquet files:

```
    data
    ├── name=Steve
    └── name=Michael
```

In SparkSQL, with the query:

```
CREATE TABLE test USING parquet OPTIONS (path 'hdfs://namenode:8020/data')
```

The partitions are not recovered properly and data is not detected:

```
SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 1

+---+----+
|ID |name|
+---+----+
+---+----+
```

However, there is an alternative by specifying the schema when creating the table and, later, perform an *alter table* with *recover partitions*

```
CREATE TABLE test2(ID Int, name String) USING parquet OPTIONS (path 'hdfs://namenode:8020/data')

ALTER TABLE test2 RECOVER PARTITIONS

SELECT * FROM test2 LIMIT 1

+----+---------+
| ID |    name |
+----+---------+
|  1 |   Steve |
|  2 | Michael |
+----+---------+
```

Is there any other alternative in Spark SQL to use partition discovery with only one query when creating the table and without specifying the schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you creating the table through spark sql such as:

```
CREATE TABLE test USING parquet OPTIONS (path 'hdfs://namenode:8020/data')
```

do remember to repair the table before you using it:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE test
```

Then the table's partitions will be registered into metastore. Otherwise the table will not return any results. As mentioned in this online document: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/tables.html

Answer (score 0):

Assume population data is loaded into a partitioned table using the following directory structure, with two extra columns, gender and country as partitioning columns:

```
path
└── to
    └── table
        ├── gender=male
        │   ├── ...
        │   │
        │   ├── country=US
        │   │   └── data.parquet
        │   ├── country=CN
        │   │   └── data.parquet
        │   └── ...
        └── gender=female
            ├── ...
            │
            ├── country=US
            │   └── data.parquet
            ├── country=CN
            │   └── data.parquet
            └── ...
```

By passing path/to/table to either SparkSession.read.parquet or SparkSession.read.load, Spark SQL will automatically extract the partitioning information from the paths. Now the schema of the returned DataFrame becomes:

```
root
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- age: long (nullable = true)
|-- gender: string (nullable = true)
|-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

Note: When you read the partitioned data using `spark.read.parquet("path/to/table/*")` and run `df.show()`, you'll find that the two extra columns (gender and country) are missing. To ensure that they are added in your dataframe, you'll have to add the basePath option as `read.option("basePath", "path/to/table").parquet("path/to/table/*")` or you can specify the path as `spark.read.parquet("path/to/table")`

If using spark.sql, then Hive parquet - provided set up fine and not on S3 which requires a repair, then spark.sql as per question provided such be partition aware.

E.g. a trivial example (cannot format for some reason):

dfX.write.partitionBy("col2").format("parquet").saveAsTable("dfX_partitionBy_Table")

But in your question, if this here is not wanted, then the answer is No.

Comment: Does it mean that partition discovery cannot be used with a SQL query and the dataframe API must be used?

Comment: The approach above is intended with spark.read... However, dfX.write.partitionBy("col2").format("parquet").saveAsTable("dfX_partitionBy_Table") should allow partition pruning to occur. Is this what you are looking for, then  I will adapt the answer.

Comment: The thing is that I need to make use of Partition Discovery in HDFS using only one SQL Query

Comment: But if you have partitioned properly, then it should work. I provided a parquet table example partition by col c2. It is in Hive metastore, so should work. Otherwise you need to clarify the problem more so.

Comment: What if Hive Support is disabled?